# remplazar asterisco (*) por etiqueta <b> segun corresponda

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente texto de ejemplo:

```
Hola bienvenido ah *tu sitio.com*

para continuar oprime *cualquier tecla*
```

lo que necesito es cambiar los asteriscos por la etiqueta `<b>` en php pero sería relativamente, que si ya abrió una etiqueta cerrarla, ósea debería quedar asi:

```
Hola bienvenido ah <b>tu sitio.com</b>

para continuar oprime <b>cualquier tecla</b>
```

tengo por ahora el siguiente código, pero no logro hacerlo:

```
$partsBlod = explode('*',$value->txt_msn);  
   if (count($partsBlod)>1) {
       $textNew = "";
       for ($i=0; $i < count($partsBlod); $i++) { 
         if ($i == 0) {
            $textNew .= $partsBlod[$i] . '<b>';
         }else{
            $textNew .= $partsBlod[$i] . '</b><b>';
         }
   }
   $value->txt_msn = $textNew;
```

Comment: Para que necesitas hacerlo de esa manera?

Comment: solo descargate esta libreria en php llamada [Markdown](https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown)

Comment: tambien esta otra [Parsedown](http://parsedown.org/) que incluye una desmostracion de uso

Comment: @Eddy o, para un caso sencillo como este, se puede resolver en una sola línea :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función [preg_replace_callback](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace-callback.php), que le pasamos como parámetros una expresión regular, una función y el texto que deseamos probar. En la expresión regular le diremos que coincida con todo lo que esté dentro de dos `*`. De esta manera:

```php
$texto = '
Hola bienvenido ah *tu sitio.com*

para continuar oprime *cualquier tecla*
';
$regex = '/\*(.*?)\*/s';

$texto = preg_replace_callback(
    $regex,
    function($matches) {
        return sprintf(
            '<b>%s</b>',
            $matches[1]
        );
    },
    $texto
);

echo '<pre>';
echo $texto;
echo '</pre>';
```

Imprimirá esto:

```php
Hola bienvenido ah <b>tu sitio.com</b>

para continuar oprime <b>cualquier tecla</b>
```

Comment: Si, lo pensé así por si no se quieren escapar los `<br>` por ejemplo

Comment: ¿Escapar todo menos brs? fácil --> `preg_replace_callback('~(.*?)(<\s*br\b[^>]*>|\z)~is',function($m){return htmlspecialchars($m[1]).$m[2];}, $texto);` ... Y podés resolver el problema de más de un asterisco en la misma línea con `/\*(.*?)\*/s`  ;-)

Comment: Si, edite mi respuesta era inservible escapar las tags :) Por otro lado con al usar el `?` regex existía un problema al tener dos `*` unidos, en todo caso tu regex funciona mejor, lo empezaré a utilizar desde ahora :D

Comment: Ese problema ya lo tenías con `.*`, pero el autor no dijo nada de dobles asteriscos

Comment: Editando.. Gracias @Mariano!!

Comment: Excelente amigos muchas gracias, funciono a la perfección, no pense hacerlo de esa manera, buena tecnica ;)

Answer (score 1):

Si se toma un asterisco en *cualquier* posición, sólo hay que reemplazar con:

```
$resultado = preg_replace( '/\*([^*]+)\*/', '<b>$1</b>', $texto);
```

La expresión regular coincide con

- `\*` un asterisco
- `([^*]+)` grupo 1 (los paréntesis capturan el texto)

  - `[^*]+` uno o más caracteres que no sean asteriscos
- `\*` el otro asterisco

Y, al reemplazarlo por `<b>$1</b>`, `$1` contiene el texto que coincidió con el grupo 1.

---

Por otro lado, si quisieras permitir secuencias de escape como `\*` en el  texto, para que el usuario pueda usar un asterisco que no signifique negritas, hay que usar este regex:

```
/\*([^\\*]*(?:\\.[^\\*]*)*)\*/
```

Comment: +1 tienes razón mi respuesta solo engloba un `<b></b>` por linea.